anchor_spl imports with token 2022
I have an initialise function, which gives the mint authority to a token which was created using the Token 2022 program.
The function looks like this.
pub fn initialize_program(
    ctx: Context<InitializeProgram>,
    usdc_mint: Pubkey
) -> Result<()> {
    let state = &mut ctx.accounts.program_state;

    // Store the mint accounts in the program state
    state.custom_token_mint = *ctx.accounts.custom_token_mint.key();  // Corrected: Use key() method
    state.usdc_mint = usdc_mint;
    state.admin = *ctx.accounts.admin.key();

    // Derive the program's PDA (Program-Derived Address)
    let (program_pda, _bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"program-pda"], ctx.program_id);

    // Step 1: Transfer mint authority of the custom token to the program's PDA
    let cpi_accounts = SetAuthority {
        account_or_mint: ctx.accounts.custom_token_mint.to_account_info(),
        current_authority: ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program_2022.to_account_info();  // Use Token Program 2022
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

    anchor_spl::token_2022::set_authority(
        cpi_ctx,
        AuthorityType::MintTokens,  // Make sure this is from spl_token_2022
        Some(program_pda)           // New authority is the program's PDA
    )?;

    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeProgram<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = admin, space = 8 + 32 + 32 + 32)]
    pub program_state: Account<'info, ProgramState>, // State account to store mint addresses
    #[account(mut)]
    pub custom_token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,     // The custom token mint
    #[account(mut)]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,                        // The admin who initializes the program
    pub token_program_2022: Program<'info, Token2022>,   // Use Token Program 2022 here
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,      // System program for account creation
}


I have these imports
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, Mint, TokenAccount, Transfer};
use spl_token_2022::instruction::AuthorityType;
use anchor_spl::token_2022::{SetAuthority, MintTo, Burn, Token2022, };

however on these few lines I get an error.
anchor_spl::token_2022::set_authority(
        cpi_ctx,
        AuthorityType::MintTokens,  // Make sure this is from spl_token_2022
        Some(program_pda)           // New authority is the program's PDA
    )?;

the error is
Type mismatch [E0308] expected `spl_token_2022::instruction::AuthorityType`, but found `AuthorityType`

as far as I can see I am importing the correct type, so I am not sure why I am getting this error?

It's hard to tell without seeing the exact dependencies you're using, but my hunch is that you're using a different major version of spl-token-2022 than Anchor is.
Be sure to specify the same major version for spl-token-2022 as anchor-spl, as defined at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/4cdb0ebe8f613f7dbbd5c4b00571139b2517898f/spl/Cargo.toml#L34
